# Travelling to UK and around Europe - visas required

Tags: visas, uk, europe

Well, this is going to be a confusing one.

Basically, my wife, first son, and myself are British citizens. We moved to Australia a few years ago (my visa is that I am a permanent resident in Australia, along with my wife and first son).

My second son was born a year ago here in Australia. He is an Australian citizen.

We are going to visit family in the UK in a few months and need to know what visas we will need, if any. Ignoring Brexit, of course (if they manage to get that passed before then, and who knows what form it will take).

Now, as I, my wife and first son are still British citizens, I imagine we don't need any visas. However, I think we'll need to apply for something for our second son.

Also, we're looking at visiting Europe whilst there. Again, as British citizens (while the UK is still part of the EU), I imagine that I, my wife and first son will be fine, but we may well need to apply for something for our second son.

Am I right in thinking this (and also that, as a family unit, we'll have to enter the UK via the "from outside the EU" queue at our destination airport), and if so what do we need to apply for?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you second son is a UK citizen? It would appear so to me. https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn will check over the weekend.

Answer (score 6):

Since you and your wife are British citizens, your second son is also a British citizen (in addition to Australian, so a dual citizen). So you need to register your second son as a British citizen, and then you can obtain a passport for him.

See the following form: [Application to register child under 18 as British citizen: form MN1](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-to-register-child-under-18-as-british-citizen-form-mn1)

If you already have a passport for him, then no other action is required. The fact that he is also an Australian citizen is no problem. Bring both passports for him. See [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) for more information. Your son's case of dual citizenship is super simple and will not surprise anybody (airline agents, border officials, etc).

Also, even if your son were to have only Australian citizenship, Australians can visit the UK without a visa for up to six months, and the Schengen area (most of Europe) for at least 90 days. So no problem either way. See [Visa requirements for Australian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens) for more information.

Comment: I should imagine so, will look this weekend. Pretty sure we've got a British passport for him.

Comment: If you've got a British passport for him already, then why would you even worry about this question?

Comment: On arrival in the UK. If you all do have UK passports you an either use the E-gates if everyone's over 12 years old or use the (at present) EU queue. The queues are based on the passport held rather than point of departure.